# Is there any way to add jar file to pycharm and run jython directly?

Tags: pycharm, jython-2.7

Here I have two questions:

1. How to add external jar file while running .py file using jython like `java -cp` command?
2. How to run .py file in pycharm using jython ?
3. How pycharm deals with external jar like eclipse `configure build path` to add specific jar file to the project?

Here is the scene I met:

download all jar htmlutil jar file from sourceforge, and then write a `gartner.py` file, here is the import snippet in source code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient as WebClient
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion as BrowserVersion
```

And run such file in command line like this:

```
jython -J-classpath "/Users/crabime/Development Folder/htmlunit-2.23/lib/*" /Users/crabime/PycharmProjects/scrapimage/crabime/gartner.py
```

It can do what I want but it's too boring and I can not check its error while writing python file, so is there any method to solve this awkwardness?

Comment: I'm testing the [JythonHelper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7362-jythonhelper) plugin.